# SysUtils.StrScan() function for string type? where?

Tags: delphi, pascal

While SysUtils.StrScan() takes PWideChar const as the parameter, is there a StrScan() like built-in function for string/Unicodestring type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain old [`Pos`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Pos) will work well enough for most cases. The second parameter will simply be a one-character `string` instead of a `Char`.

If the string you're searching through will not have embedded null characters, then you can also use `StrScan` directly; just type-cast the string parameter to `PChar`. `StrScan` will stop searching when it reaches the null character.

Comment: Yes, but since the plain Pos() was designed to search a substring, its internal code should be not optimal for searching a single character. OK, I think I will still use StrScan() like this: pTempPtr := Pointer(SomeString); Position := StrScan(pTempPtr, AChar) - pTempPtr);

Comment: I mean PChar typecasting versus the bare Pointer typecasting?

Comment: Is there a downside by using Pointer typecasting instead of PChar typecasting? I see the compiler will generate less code with Pointer typecasting.

Comment: Always cast to the most specific type available. The function asks for a character pointer, so give it one. Also, type-casting to Pointer will yield a *null* pointer if the string is empty, which is not what the function wants. Finally, it might be worth looking at the `Pos` implementation to see whether it has any optimizations for searching for short strings. (There'd still be a hit for *allocating* the string, though.)

Comment: I assume POS is overloaded for single characters.

Comment: @Macro: Pos() is not overloaded for single chars but its algorithm searches for the first char in the substring first. So if you have a 1-char substring, it isn't that slow.

Comment: Pos() is overloaded in FPC, but not in Delphi. IMO, Delphi should follow FPC in this case to generate more optimized code.